# Choosing opengis or geotools imports dealing with geotools library?

Tags: java, style, geotools

In some cases, I have to use some classes of GeoTools library.

Most of class names are duplicated in `org.geotools` and `org.opengis` package. for example, `StyleVisitor`, `Symbolizer`, `PointSymbolizer`, etc.

I want to know which one of them I should use in my project in usual coding.

### import#1:

```
import org.geotools.styling.Graphic;
import org.geotools.styling.LineSymbolizer;
import org.geotools.styling.Mark;
import org.geotools.styling.PointSymbolizer;
```

### import#2:

```
import org.opengis.style.Graphic;
import org.opengis.style.LineSymbolizer;
import org.opengis.style.Mark;
import org.opengis.style.PointSymbolizer;
```

### My code:

```
public class MyStylePainter extends StylePainter {

    private MyStylePainter(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);

    }

    public void setWidthAndHeight(PointSymbolizer pointS) {
        double d = 15;
        double size = size(pointS.getGraphic());
        double realSize = d * size;
        int width = (int) Math.round(realSize);
        this.setWidth(width);
        this.setHeight(width);
    }

    protected static double size(Graphic graphic) {
      double size = 1;
      if (graphic.getSize() != null) {
          size = Filters.asDouble(graphic.getSize());
      }
      if (size <= 0) {
          size = .2d;
      }
      return size;
    }
}
```

Do I use **import#1** or **import#2** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; in general use the `org.geotools` imports if you are working solely with [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) code.

As is documented in the [OpenGIS FAQ GeoTools](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/opengis/faq.html) once upon a time had idealistic developers who thought the world would be a better place if the "Java GIS Tribe" could share code more easily. So they built a set of interfaces that people implementing various [OGC](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards) and [ISO](http://www.isotc211.org/) specifications could use as a basis for their concrete implementations. In this way they hoped that interoperability would be enhanced and the world would be a sunnier and happier place :-)

Sadly this never really came to pass.

These days the main value of the `org.opengis.*` interfaces is that they represent a "clean" version of the standard and the corresponding `org.geotools.*` interface may well have been extended to include other useful methods that make the standard easier to use or more useful to the average developer.